# Given $ \equiv 4\pmod{13}$, and $ \equiv 9\pmod{13}$. If $\equiv ^2+^2\pmod{13}$ with $0\leq c \leq 12$ . Find the value of $c$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

****For the following** question**:
Given $ \equiv 4 \pmod{13}$, and $ \equiv 9\pmod{13}$. If  $\equiv ^2+^2\pmod{13}$ with $0\leq c \leq 12$ . Find the value of $c$.

Here is my attempt  :

$a^2 \equiv 4 \cdot 4 \pmod{13}$

$a^2 \equiv 16 \pmod{13}$

$b^2 \equiv 9\cdot 9 \pmod{13}$

$b^2 \equiv 81 \pmod{13}$

then

$a^2+b^2 \equiv 81+16 \pmod{13}$

$a^2+b^2 \equiv 97 \pmod{13}$

then

$c \equiv a^2+b^2 \equiv 97  \equiv 6 \pmod{13}$

and hence $c=6$.
Is my solution correct? More specifically, for $a^2$ and $b^2$  where I have multiplied the congruent relations of $a$ and $b$ by themselves, is that right?

Comment: What are $a2$ and $b2$?

Comment: do you mean $c \equiv 2a + 2b \mod 13$ or $c\equiv a^2 + b^2 \mod 13$? I suppose the latter.

Comment: @Bernard . edited . Sorry

Comment: Please use proper MathJax.

Comment: You've been a user here for three and a half years. Don't you think it's time you learnt MathJax?

Comment: @Student  yes.  This was a typo

Comment: Also, your first line is $\mod 13$, the second becomes $\mod 3$. I suppose that's a typo too. Pleas follow Shaun's suggestion and use MathJax to make questions more readible.

Comment: Yes, it's correct (mod typos), by using the Congruence Laws in the linked dupe. Easier: $\,a\equiv 4\Rightarrow a^2\equiv 4^2\equiv 3,\,$ $\, b\equiv 9\equiv -4\Rightarrow b^2\equiv (-4)^2\equiv 3,\,$ so $\,a^2+b^2\equiv 3+3\ \ $

Comment: Also, not related to this question, but after looking at your profile I couldn't help but notice that you don't accept answers. If answers are helpful, you should accept them :)

Comment: You can find many more examples of congruence arithmetic in the Linked posts in the dupe, and well as [searching in the modular arithmetic tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modular-arithmetic?tab=Votes).

Comment: More generally $\,a+b\equiv 0\Rightarrow b\equiv -a\Rightarrow a^2+b^2\equiv a^2+(-a)^2\equiv 2a^2\ \ $

Comment: @Student: If you don't know how to properly type it up in MathJax, then kindly do not try to "help". That is a true mess.

Comment: This is probably an opportune time to mention **meta-cheating**.  Since you are not given the exact values of $a$ or $b$, then you can presume that the answer is independent of the exact values.  This means (to a certain extent) you can ignore Number Theory and assume that $a = 4, b = 9, ~$ **exactly**.  That is, by **meta-cheating**, if you compute with those exact values for $a,b$, and if the problem is solvable, then your computation **must** achieve the (unique) intended answer.  I mention this because in both high school and college math, **meta-cheating** is a powerful weapon.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I kept the original structure of OP's answer, just corrected typos, added missing exponentsigns and added '$'. Looking at your edits, I learned about the pmod-command, so thank you!